# I transfered my Swift IOS Project to another mac, however I am getting errors on #selector lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I recently transfered my IOS project to another mac. But every file with #selector method is giving my syntax errors now. They worked fine before. I am relatively new to Swift so I have no idea what might be the issue here.

How do I get rid of those errors?

Example code:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyController.clicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
```

Example error:

```
Expected ',' seperator
```

Comment: Are you sure the XCode version is the same on both?

Comment: XCode versions are differents, upgrade the version where you have synthax errors.

Comment: Thanks! It seems my new xcode is outdated.